# KeyError: 'DATABASE_URL'

Tags: django, sqlite, postgresql, heroku

I need help with this issue.

When I start processes locally using foreman start
I get this output.

```
 21:59:18 web.1  |     DB_URI = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']
 21:59:18 web.1  |   File        "/Users/radhikasrinivasan/myproject/venv/bin/../lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in   __getitem__
21:59:18 web.1  |     raise KeyError(key)
21:59:18 web.1  | KeyError: 'DATABASE_URL'
21:59:18 web.1  | exited with code 1
21:59:18 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
SIGTERM received
```

In settings.py if this helps. When the app is deployed in Heroku it is in **Heroku Postgres :: Orange**

```
 DATABASES = {
          'default': {
                      'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 
                           #'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
                       #'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
              }
}

 #Connecting with Django
     import dj_database_url
     DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config(default='sqlite://db/sqlite3.db')
```

Thank you,
Rads

Comment: Why have you commented out the `NAME` parameter. It is required

Comment: There was a mistake in Allowed_hosts[]. It is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you don't have an environment variable `DATABASE_URL` declared, or it would be visible in `os.environ` dict.

**EDIT**

Not a Heroku expert, but maybe you should follow this:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#setting-up-config-vars-for-a-deployed-application

Comment: There was a mistake in Allowed_hosts[]. It is resolved. Thank you for sharing the link.

Comment: Rads, pleace accept the answer if you think it helped to solve ;)

Comment: Hi Tonjo, I am getting this error at the moment. It has not resolved yet. ImportError: No module named django.core.management
14:37:48 web.1  | sh: gunicorn: command not found

Comment: After adding **Add some config vars for your S3 account keys:**

Comment: foreman start
14:37:46 web.1  | started with pid 1701
14:37:48 web.1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
14:37:48 web.1  |   File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
14:37:48 web.1  |     from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
14:37:48 web.1  | ImportError: No module named django.core.management
14:37:48 web.1  | sh: gunicorn: command not found
14:37:48 web.1  | exited with code 127
14:37:48 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
SIGTERM received

Comment: manage.py ---------------------------------------------------#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

Comment: I am not sure how to change s3 key in manage.py  **s3 = S3Client(os.environ['S3_KEY'], os.environ['S3_SECRET'])
**

Comment: Maybe now it's late, but `django.core.management` not found means you don't jave Django installed? And for `S3_KEY` it's the same as `DATABASE_URL`